# How to change date format to dd mmm yyyy in rdlc report?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, crystal-reports

How can I change the date format in a Microsoft report?

Comment: =Format(Fields!YourDate.Value, "dd mmm yyyy")

Comment: I tried for today's date but It did not work. It show like 17 00 2015

Comment: @CodingDefined lowercase `m` is for minutes, uppercase `M` is for months

Answer (score 5):

You can use below line of code:

```
Format(Fields!YourDateField.Value,"dd-MMM-yyyy")
```

See the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) link for more information.

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

I found answer with this =Format(Now, "dd MMM yyyy")